# integration by parts of an exponent

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to calculate an integral in 2 different ways: direct calculation, and integration by parts. I'm getting 2 different results and I can't figure out the reason.
the integral is:

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\partial_x^2f(x) dx$$
where $f(x) = e^{-\frac{|x|}{a}}$ and $\partial_x=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

the derivatives are therefore: $\partial_x f(x) = -\frac{sgn(x)}{a}e^{-\frac{|x|}{a}} , 
\partial_x^2f(x) = (-\frac{sgn(x)}{a})^2e^{-\frac{|x|}{a}} = \frac{1}{a^2}e^{-\frac{|x|}{a}}$

the first method, a direct calculation, gives the following:
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{|x|}{a}}(-\frac{1}{a})^2e^{-\frac{|x|}{a}}dx = 
\frac{1}{a^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{2|x|}{a}}dx $$

the second method, integration by parts, gives the following:
$$
I = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\partial_xf(x))^2 dx= -\int_{-\infty}^\infty (-\frac{sgn(x)}{a}e^{-\frac{|x|}{a}})^2dx = -\frac{1}{a^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{2|x|}{a}}dx
$$
where the first term of the integration by parts is zero since $f(|x|\rightarrow\infty) = 0$.

overall, we get a minus sign deifference at the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integration-by-parts relation $\int uv'=[uv]-\int u'v$ is only guaranteed to work if $u'$ and $v'$ are continuous. Here $v'=f'(x)$ is discontinuous by the sign function.